# R - Parsing XML from SharePoint List

Tags: r, xml, sharepoint

I am collecting data from a SharePoint list. The connection works; however, the list is limited to 1,000 items when there are more than 25,000 items in the full list. The same connection with Tableau and Excel provides the full list.

```
URL <- "http://XXXXXX/XXXXXX/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RequiredLearningStatus"
URL_parsed <- xmlParse(readLines(URL,warn=F))
items <- getNodeSet(URL_parsed, "//m:properties")
x <- xmlToDataFrame(items, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I receive the following error message when the readLines() function executes:

"In readLines(URL): incomplete final line found"

How can I deal with the EOL error and retrieve the full list?

Answer (score 1):

I only have a basic understanding here, but I will try to assist, since there are no answers as of yet, and I have been successful myself.

The structure of the URL I use for pulling in my SP list (includes all items) uses the GUID of the list, like so:

```
"https://XXXX/XXXX/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE&List={<<YOUR GUID HERE>>}"
```

To get your GUID, I've plagiarized from this [link](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/):

> There are times when you need to find the Id (a Guid) of a list – for
>   example, when setting the Task list to be used with SharePoint
>   Designer Workflows (see my blog post here). Here’s a simple way of
>   doing this:
>
> - Navigate to the SharePoint list using the browser.
> - Select the Settings + List Settings menu command.
> - Copy the Url from the browser address bar into Notepad. It will look something like:
>
>   - `http://moss2007/ProjectX/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B26534EF9%2DAB3A%2D46E0%2DAE56%2DEFF168BE562F%7D`
> - Delete everying before and including “List=”.
> - Change “%7B” to “{”
> - Change all “%2D” to “-“
> - Change “%7D” to “}”
>
> You are now left with the Id:
>
> `{26534EF9-AB3A-46E0-AE56-EFF168BE562F}`

Once you've got that URL, I am reading in the data in a slightly different fashion:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(data.table)

URL <- "https://XXXX/XXXX/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE&List={<<YOUR GUID HERE>>}"
xml <- xmlParse(getURL(URL, userpwd='<<youruser>>:<<yourpass>>'))
finalData <- data.table(do.call(rbind,xmlToList(xmlRoot(xml)[['data']]))
```

In the code above, be sure to replace `<<YOUR GUID HERE>>` and `<<youruser>>:<<yourpass>>` with appropriate values for your environment. There should be no `<` or `>` in any of the code (aside from R's assignment, `<-`).

Comment: I am receiving a new error message when using your solution: 

Error: 1: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
2: attributes construct error
3: Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 4
4: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: @DaleKube I have to make sure, did you replace `<<YOUR GUID HERE>>` and `<<youruser>>:<<yourpass>>` with appropriate values for your environment? Maybe I should have pointed it out in my original answer, and I'll update now, but there should be no `<` or `>` in any of that code.

Comment: Yes. I replaced those pieces with appropriate values. I did not include the carets in the code.

Comment: Are you able to manually step through each line in your console and isolate which specific line is hitting the error? (I'm looking at either the `xml <-` or `finalData <-`, but I'm not familiar with that error to know off hand.)

Comment: Within this section `xml <- xmlParse(getURL(URL, userpwd='username:password'))`, the `getURL` call returns the following error message embded within the returned XML: "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator".

Comment: Do you have some item/element in your list that's incompatible? That may explain why both methods are failing.